# React Router 3: What is the effect of brackets () in a route's path definition?

Tags: react-router

I have a react router 3 component that is specified as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  path: 'report(/:skip)',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./Containers/Report').default);
    });
  },
};
```

My question is about the `'report(/:skip)'` line. I understand that `report/:skip` would match `report/foo` and then pass `foo` into the params hash available to the component, but what is the effect of the brackets around `/:skip`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the brackets mean the parameter is optional, as explained in the API docs [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md):

> - `()` – Wraps a portion of the URL that is optional. You may escape
>     parentheses if you want to use them in a url using a backslash \